# How to increase bubble size in bubble chart in apex chart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I am using apexcharts 3.48.0 and react apexcharts 1.4.1 version .
I am drawing a bubble chart but the largest bubble size is very small. I am trying to increase bubble size by the following code

plotOptions: {

```
bubble: {
  zScaling: true,
  minBubbleRadius: 5,
  maxBubbleRadius: 8000,
```

}

but big bubble size are not increase after certain size .

code on codesandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/trusting-babycat-nyxl56?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FApexBubbleMapExample.tsx%3A4%2C1

Thanks

Supriya Singh